# UV Mapping doesn't consider Camera Background Image Rotation of 90° for vertical images

Tags: uv

I would like to make a fairly simple projective mapping setup:

[image]

And because Blender automatically rotates vertical images, I had to apply 90° to the Camera Background Image:

[image]

And this causes the UV Mapping Project From View to fail:

[image]

Is there any way to make this work with vertical images?

Comment: What version of blender are you using? My background image properties lack a rotation factor in both 2.93 and 3.0

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I used Blender 2.92 for this. I figured out the strange behaviour, iPhone is saving vertical images horizontally and then just adds some JPG Meta Information... and this may only be half-integrated by Blender or so.

Comment: The UV mapping projection has nothing to do with the background image. It just projects the mapping coordinates. You still have to make a shader with the image texture and then you can rotate the image in the shader using the mapping node if you wish.